# MBProgressHud View Customization Not Work In Swift 3 And Not Showing?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, mbprogresshud

i am using the following code but not showing progress hud so please help for that.simple hud showing fine but customise not showing

```
let loadingHUD = MBProgressHUD() 

loadingHUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView
loadingHUD.labelText = nil
loadingHUD.detailsLabelText = nil
let customView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80))

let gifmanager = SwiftyGifManager(memoryLimit:20)
let gif = UIImage(gifName: "miniballs1.gif")
let imageview = UIImageView(gifImage: gif, manager: gifmanager)
imageview.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: customView.frame.width, height: customView.frame.height)
customView.addSubview(imageview)
customView.bringSubview(toFront: imageview)

loadingHUD.customView = customView
loadingHUD.customView.bringSubview(toFront: customView)
loadingHUD.show(true)
```

Comment: Try this HUD library for iOS in swift https://github.com/shubh10/JustHUD

Comment: thanks .. but's i have solved this issue and working for me fine

Comment: That's great. That is my library though, try it when you get time. Feel free to share it with your friends and add new features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this library ACProgressHud-Swift

In xib file whatever view make then customise and use it.

For Show

```
ACProgressHUD.shared.showHUD(withStatus: “Your Message Name“)
```

For hide

```
ACProgressHUD.shared.hideHUD()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.this is easy to use HUD . i integrate in my project and working fine.

Answer (score 4):

I Solved This Problem  In Swift 3

```
   var hud = MBProgressHUD()


 hud.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


// Set an image view with a checkmark.
let gifmanager = SwiftyGifManager(memoryLimit:20)
let gif = UIImage(gifName: "eclipse.gif")
let imageview = UIImageView(gifImage: gif, manager: gifmanager)
hud.labelText = NSLocalizedString(string, comment: "")
hud.labelColor = UIColor.red

imageview.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: 80 , height: 80)

let views = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: 80 , height: 80))
views.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
views.addSubview(imageview)

hud.customView = views

hud.customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
hud.dimBackground = true

    hud.show(true)
```

Comment: Try this HUD library for iOS in swift https://github.com/shubh10/JustHUD

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class Loader:  NSObject {


class func setup()
{
    MBProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.Black)
    MBProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7))
    MBProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1))

}

class func Show(message:String = "loading..."){

    MBProgressHUD.showWithStatus(message)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

}

class func Hide(){
    MBProgressHUD.dismiss()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}
}
```

Make a class of MBProgressHUD and use it as `Loader.Show()` Or you can customise it as per your requirement

Comment: I Want to use MBProgressHudCustom View Use And For this type loading animation already work for me